# Will forEach leak in a Dart's Broadcast Stream?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

I have a `StreamController.broadcast()` which I pass its `Steam` to many of my Flutter Widgets at creation.

Since at each `build` I will be recreating those Widgets, I wonder if using `Stream.forEach()` inside those Widgets won't lead to memory leaks, as `forEach()` has no mechanism to close the `Subscription`. I wonder if maybe those `Subscription` object won't get cleaned-up, or even if the Widgets themselves won't get out of memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will.

The listener is maintained until the stream ends or emits an error.

So if you do `Stream.forEach` inside `build`, then any rebuild of the widget will add a listener without removing the previous one.

Comment: Ok, so I will replace it with a `listen` and call `cancel` on my `State.dispose`, thanks!